# Display a PDF embedded in an XML file with XSL

Tags: xml, pdf, xslt

I have an XML file that contains a PDF stream in the nonXMLBody node.

```
<nonXMLBody><text mediaType="application/pdf" representation="B64">JVBERi0xLjQNCiXT9MzhDQoxIDAgb2JqDQo8PCA+Pg0KZW5kb2JqDQoyIDAgb2JqDQo8PCAvVHlwZSAvQ2F0YWxvZw0KICAgL1BhZ2VzIDMgMCBSDQogICAvUGllY2VJbmZvIDw8IC9FT1BERiA8PCAvVmVyc2lvbiAoNC4wLjUwLjIpIC9GbGFncyAxID4+DQogICAgPj4NCj4
...
DAwMDAwIG4NCjAwMDAwNTczMzAgMDAwMDAgbg0KMDAwMDA1NzU5OCAwMDAwMCBuDQowMDAwMDU3ODgzIDAwMDAwIG4NCjAwMDAwNjkxNjkgMDAwMDAgbg0KMDAwMDA2OTU1MSAwMDAwMCBuDQp0cmFpbGVyDQo8PCAvUm9vdCAyIDAgUg0KICAgL0luZm8gMSAwIFINCiAgIC9JRCBbPDA5NTZGNDk2MUU5QzI4MUYyMEY5RjEzQUI1MUY4QzU5PiA8MDk1NkY0OTYxRTlDMjgxRjIwRjlGMTNBQjUxRjhDNTk+XQ0KICAgL1NpemUgMjENCj4+DQpzdGFydHhyZWYNCjcwMzg1DQolJUVPRg0K</text></nonXMLBody>
```

Is there a way using an XSL template to display the pdf AS a pdf similar to the way I would do it if it was plain text

```
<xsl:template match='n1:component/n1:nonXMLBody'>
    <xsl:choose>
        <!-- if there is a reference, use that in an IFRAME -->
        <xsl:when test='n1:text/n1:reference'>
            <IFRAME name='nonXMLBody' id='nonXMLBody' WIDTH='80%' HEIGHT='600' src='{n1:text/n1:reference/@value}'/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test='n1:text/@mediaType="text/plain"'>
            <pre>
                <xsl:value-of select='n1:text/text()'/>
            </pre>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <CENTER>Cannot display the text</CENTER>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

Or do I need to use something else to get it to display on the page and exclude the nonXMLBody in the xsl template?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried a `data` URI in the form of `<iframe src="application/xml;base64,{text[@mediaType = 'application/pdf']}" ...></iframe>`?

Comment: when i'm putting in the src, do I need to do n1:text/@mediaType or the way you have it written here is the correct syntax?

Comment: If a namespace is used then you probably want `<iframe src="application/xml;base64,{n1:text[@mediaType = 'application/pdf']}" ...></iframe>` or if you want to take the type from your input then `<iframe src="{n1:text/@mediaType};base64,{n1:text[@mediaType = 'application/pdf']}" ...></iframe>`.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working. I used both of the tweaks you put here. All I'm getting now is a blank iframe.

Comment: I have tried a data URI here locally, with Firefox and Chrome the iframe displays the PDF, with Edge and IE not. Which browser do you target, does it have built-in support for PDF rendering?

Comment: Issue might be I'm looking at it in IE. Going to need both IE and Chrome (and potentially firefox and safari). It's got to have cross browser compatibility. I also tried it in chrome, but I get an error: HTTP Error 414. The request URL is too long.

Comment: I don't know of a way to inline the data other than with a `data` URI and if Chrome indicates the data is too long then it does not look like a feasible approach. So I guess you will have to create separate PDF files and link to them/load them as needed.